# use correct path of folder in win app

Tags: c#

I write a win app,now i want to make setup for my app project.i have a folder in the
root path of my project and it contains some wave files that i use theire path
in my app like: "F:\test\Resources\1.wav".
now my queistion is: how can i use their path in correct format ,that if i install setup file,on
another computer my app works true ,only because of the path of the wave files.

thanks alot for your attention.

Answer (score 2):

You can get your EXE's path by calling  `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`.

Alternatively you could store you install path in the registry somewhere with the installer and then you can check that registry entry.

Comment: @na.fa: Which part do you want me to explain?

Comment: System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.this code what do?

Comment: if i use Application.StartupPath + @"\Resources\1.wav" for addresing ,would i have problem ?thanks.

Comment: @na.fa: That's fine as well or you can just use @"Resources\1.wav"

Answer (score 2):

You can use`Application.StartupPath`, and append your subfolder.

So something like `Application.StartupPath + @"\Resources\1.wav"` should do the trick.

This is without Reflection, so I guess it will be a little faster, but I haven't benchmarked it.